# Mathematical Symbol

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

In the following [paper](http://www.intelligenthedgefundinvesting.com/pubs/rb-cb.pdf), what does the symbol $\Phi$ in equation $3.1$ (page $3$) represent? Does it represent the normal distribution?

Comment: I am new to brownian motion but it seems to be related to this topic. Sorry if this question is vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Phi(x)$ typically (and which is what is also means in the article you have linked to) represents a suitably normalized error function, equivalently the cummulative distribution function of the normal distribution, i.e.,
$$\Phi(x) = \dfrac1{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x} \exp(-t^2/2)dt$$

Comment: so in the PDF, the variables inside the phi symbol represents a point on the CDF correct? So phi(0) should equal 0.5?

Comment: @user1234440 Yes. $\Phi(0) = 0.5$. I got confused with your use of PDF (probability density function/ portable document format) :-).

Comment: Sorry! I am trying to code up in R the expected drawdown equation E(D), but am not getting results similar to the graph shown in the next page.